# Assign variable in JSP file to Java String

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I have this variable `${baseURL}` which is set like so

```
<c:set var="baseURL" value="${fn:replace(pageContext.request.requestURL, 
  pageContext.request.requestURI, pageContext.request.contextPath)}" />
```

I need to assign it to a Java String or pass it into a Java function within the same jsp file.

Comment: Can you be more specific like where are you stuck, share if there are any exceptions, values of `pageContext.request` etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign a JSTL variable to a JAVA variable by getting its value using `pageContext.getAttribute()` method as follow:

```
<% Strig s = (String)pageContext.getAttribute("baseURL"); %>
```